# Discord.NET c# getting the roles of a specific user

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Im doing a !user @ commands which gives info about the user mentioned but when getting the roles i get this error **Unable to cast object of type 'Discord.WebSocket.SocketGlobalUser' to type 'Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser'.**

This is how i'm doing it:

```
[Command("user")]
public async Task Info(string user)
```

```
var client = Context.Client;
ulong id = Convert.ToUInt64(user);
var socketUser = client.GetUser(id);

string a = string.Empty;
foreach (SocketRole role in ((SocketGuildUser)socketUser).Roles) //Problem is on this line
{
   a += role.Mention + " ";
}
```

but it doesnt seem to work. I've tried SocketUser instead of SocketGuildUser but nothing.
Help

Comment: Why don't you simply accept SocketGuildUser as your command parameter?

Comment: can you show your SocketGlobalUser and SocketGuildUser

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```cs
[Command("user")]
public async Task Info(IGuildUser user)
{
   string a = "";

   foreach (IRole role in user.Roles)
   {
      a += role.Mention + " ";
   }
}
```

This is a simpler way of getting a guild user, and also prevents your issue with fetching roles. Your problem is that you are getting a global Discord user, and trying to convert to a guild user. An alternative would be `Context.Guild.GetUserAsync(userId)`, as opposed to `Context.Client.GetUser(id);`